# How much can I get with reporting on Google Adwords API as compared to Google Analytics API linked to a Google Adwords account?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I'm currently working on a reporting module using [Google Analytics API (v4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) linked to a [Google Adwords account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961?hl=en).

While it does manage to query data based on a selection of criteria from the [Google Dimension and Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=user,session,traffic_sources,adwords,goal_conversions,platform_or_device,geo_network,system,social_activities,page_tracking,content_grouping,internal_search,site_speed,app_tracking,event_tracking,ecommerce,social_interactions,user_timings,exceptions,content_experiments,custom_variables_or_columns,time,doubleclick_campaign_manager,audience,adsense,ad_exchange,doubleclick_for_publishers,doubleclick_for_publishers_backfill,lifetime_value_and_cohorts,channel_grouping,related_products,doubleclick_bid_manager,doubleclick_search) from a linked Google Adwords account, I am unable to query data such as Click Type Performance (the one that shows Headline, Sitelink, etc) or Ad Extension Performance from Adwords through the GA API.

I do know that [Google Adwords API](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start) is able to provide reporting functionality as well but is the API thorough enough to pull data such as Click Type Performance and Ad Extension Performance?

In other words, what does Google Adwords reporting API provide that GA API linked to a Google Adwords account can't do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about programming

Comment: @Clive how is the Google Analytics api not programming related.

Comment: Programming against the api is to do with programming. Comparing it against another api is of course not about programming. It’s about comparing what two services, which could be used in the context of programming, do or don’t have in common wrt to available data. Case in point, check your answer. There’s nothing related to programming in there either

Answer (score -1):

The Google Analytics is a website for displaying analytics about web and mobile applications.   Google Adwords is is an  online advertising website.  they are two different systems.

The Google Analytics API can only return to you Google Analitcs data. That being limited to the dimensions and metrics found in the Google Dimension and Metrics Explorer.

The Adwords API can only return to you data for adwords.

> What does Google Adwords reporting API provide that GA API linked to a Google Adwords account can't do?

Adwords returns analitics based upon the ads you are currently running.   Google analytics api returns your website analytics data.